# does addEventListener callback execute function call asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, addeventlistener

I have the following function.

```
projectImageVariable.map(projectImageContainer => projectImageContainer.addEventListener("click", event => {
    revealIframe(event);
    renderGitHubButton(event);        
    renderLoadingSpinner(event);        
    loadIframesContent(event);
    removeLoadingSpinner(event);
}));
```

It does exactly what it is supposed to be doing. I don't understand why though. removeLoadingSpinner(event) fires only after loadIframesContent(event) has done it's job. That can only work if the function calls are executed asynchronous. How is that possible without using the async and await keywords? Also loadIframesContent(event) doesn't return anything. It only produces a side effect (basically adding a src - attribute with an url to the relevant dom element). How does the function call after this know when to fire?

Comment: Methods executing in order, only after the previous methods end, means they are *synchronous*, not asynchronous.

Comment: Event handlers are effectively asynchronous.  But that doesn't mean the contents of the handler are (a)synchronous.  Their actual definitions will determine if they are or are not asynchronous.

Comment: loadIframesContent(event) triggers the retrieval of data from an api. This doesn't happen instandly. It takes some time for the data to be fully loaded. Since I don't use the await keyword on this function call shouldn't removeLoadingSpinner(event) fire directly after the previous function call without waiting for the loading of the data to be finished?

Comment: If `loadIframesContent` performs asynchronous logic, yes, `removeLoadingSpinner` would be capable of executing before `loadIframesContent` finishes its asynchronous logic.

Comment: How do I know if a function performs asynchronous?

Comment: "retrieval of data from an api" can be presumed to involve a web request of some nature.  web requests and asynchronous in nature unless made otherwise.

Comment: Exactly what happens is this: If the webpage ist opened the content of an iframe is loaded. Said content is an app which is deployed on heroku. So apparently this is an synchronous process. Shouldn't it block the rest of the app while it is beeing executed?